# AIR SDK: performance of SWF compiled into iOS native app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

It's a great thing that it's possible to compile an SWF into iOS native app. I think AIR is now the best option to write e.g. small games or interactive books. Of cause AIR app will be slowler than the same app written on e.g. objective C. The question is how slower AIR app will be. Can **simple** AIR apps be launched e.g. on iPhone 3G or iPAd 1?

And another question is, can arbitrary flash app be compiled into iOS native app?

Will be grateful for **any** thoughts!!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Performance of AIR vs. Objective C:

For pure script execution, AIR apps perform rather slower than native, including on iOS. **However**, in virtually all cases the limiting factor of your app's performance will be rendering, not script, so it depends entirely on what you do visually in your content. This is why Crooksy suggested you look at Starling. Without Starling (or similar libraries that make use of the GPU), it's pretty challenging to get decent performance out of an iPad1. It can be done, but it takes expertise and incurs extra work. It will be much better to start with the huge performance boost of using Starling or similar.

1. Can arbitrary flash app be compiled into iOS native app?

As long as it's made with AS3, then it should compile. For whether it works, two main caveats come to mind: First, a handful of APIs don't work on mobile devices. (I think printing is one example.) Second, if you read in any SWFs at runtime, all actionscript inside them will be ignored. (Not for technical reasons, it's an Apple requirement.) So if your content is split into a bunch of SWFs you'll need to bundle them together at packaging time, and if you absolutely depend on reading in SWFs with script from the network at runtime, you're going to hit a wall.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! And can I compile interactive books drawn in Flash Pro?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the new Starling frame work.

http://gamua.com/

Here's the start of a nice tutorial series (episodes 1 and 2)

http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/

Lee Brimelow also has a few tutorials

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/

Regarding converting Flash apps into iOS compatible apps, yes that is possible but it depends on what the app actually does as to whether any modifications will be needed before it will perform correctly on a device.

Comment: Yes, I understand that some functions operating e.g. with filesystem are ok on desktop and will break down on iPad. Still the question was can I get an app (no matter how buggy it will be) from **any** swf.